# Output for an implementation of a Monte Carlo numerical solver for a 1D potential well doesn't match expected output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to implement a numerical solver for a 1D Harmonic well's ground state using the Metropolis algorithm and the Feynman Path Integral technique in Python. When I run my program, I end with a distribution of the different points that my particle has gone to; this distribution ought to match up with that of a particle trapped in a 1D harmonic well. It does not. I have gone through and rewritten my code; I have checked it to similar code used for the same purpose; it all looks like it should work, yet it doesn't.

[In blue is the histogram of my results, with Density set to True; the orange line is the function describing the expected distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onM20.png)
As can be seen in the image, what I have ended up with is a distribution that isn't dissimilar to what I was expecting, but it isn't the correct distribution. The code I used (see below), is based on [Lepage (2005)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-lat/0506036.pdf) work on the same topic, although I used a slightly different formula to describe the same physical system.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


time = 4        #time over which we evolve our function
steps = 7       #number of steps we take
epsilon = 3     #the pos & neg bounds of our rand variable
N_cor = 100     #the number of times we need to thermalise our function before we take a path 
N_cf = 20000    #the number of paths we take

def S(x, j, t, s):  #the action of our potential well
    e = t / s
    return (1/(2*e))*(x[j] - x[j - 1])**2 + ((x[j] + x[j-1])/2)**2/2

def update(x, t, s, eps):
    for j in range(0, s):
        old_x = x[j]                                    #old x value
        old_Sj = S(x, j, t, s)                          #original action value
        x[j] = x[j] + random.uniform(-eps,eps)          #new x value
        dS = S(x, j, t, s) - old_Sj                     #change in action
        if dS > 0 and np.exp(-dS) < random.uniform(0,1):    #check for Metropolis alg
            x[j] = old_x
    return x

def gamma(t, s, eps, thermal_num, num_paths):
    zeros = np.zeros(s)                 #our initial path with s steps
    gamma_arr = np.empty(0)             #our initial empty result
    for i in range(0, 10*thermal_num):  #thermalisation
        zeros = update(zeros, t, s, eps)
    for j in range(0, num_paths):
        for i in range(0, thermal_num):                 #thermalising again
            zeros = update(zeros, t, s, eps)
        gamma_arr = np.append(gamma_arr, zeros)         #add new path post thermalising
        #print(zeros)
        #print(gamma_arr)
    return gamma_arr

test = gamma(time, steps, epsilon, N_cor, N_cf)

x = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.1)
y = 1/np.sqrt(np.pi)*np.exp(-(x**2))    #expected result

plt.hist(test, bins= 500, density = True)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is there a specific question here?  You say your code produces the wrong answer, yet you don't indicate what the correct answer should be, nor do you explain why you think your answer is incorrect..

Comment: In the question body I linked an example of my results; plotted out against the result is the plot of the distribution I expected, which would follow 1/sqrt(pi)*exp(-x^2). I apologise for not being clearer.